# How can I add a continuosly incrementing value even from outside the program?

Tags: python, csv, variables

So, for a project at work I need to develop a test bench that works with EtherCAT and I've decided to use Python. While everything is running okay, I need to add a last point. The test bench analyzes some parameters and then stores them in a csv file. The name of the CSV file is .csv but to prevent overwriting I'd like to add a continuosly growing counter after the serial number, and also to keep track of the number of tests. So, for the first the it should be _1.csv then _2.csv and so on. Below is the way I create the csv. How can I add that variable in the end and keep track of it?

```
serial_number = str(plc_adress.read_by_name(
    'MAIN.Serial', pyads.PLCTYPE_STRING))
print(type(serial_number))
csv_serial_number = (serial_number + ".csv")
start_log = plc_adress.read_by_name(
    'Test_2_Ladder.Start_CSV', pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you read all the csv files in your directory with a given serial number, find the largest number (the `int(filename.split("_")[-1])` one) and increment it?

Comment: And you can use `glob.glob('_*.csv') ` to get a list of the existing files, then sort them to get the latest.

Comment: trying using timestamping. if not possible, use util counter file. you will need to maintain  the util counter file in script.

Comment: Store the value in a separate configuration file which can be read and updated (rewritten) as needed.

Comment: Counting the csv files is not an option: sometimes the directory will be cleaned. Since I'm a very beginner, what's with that configuration file you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the way I've done it is to create a separate Prog.dat file which has just the progressive number inside. Every time I run the program, this opens the file, reads the number, add that to the filename and adds 1 on the number in the Prog file.